# channel filtering in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, real-time

I need to **filter OpenCV frames** (that I get from a queue) on both **hue and saturation** in real-time. There are basically two techniques of which I can think of:

1. Copy the frame to HSV using `cv2.cvtColor()`, then use the copy to filter the original BGR frame, giving something such as:

   ```
   frame = queue2.get()
   imh = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.cv.CV_BGR2HSV)
   frame[(imh[...,1]<30) | (imh[...,2]<100)]=0
   ```
2. Split the HSV copy into individual channels by using `cv2.split()`, then `cv2.threshold` on hue and saturation channels, then finally reconstitute the filtered image with `cv2.merge`.

Does someone please have another **faster** idea to filter on both hue and saturation? Because I am having some issues with my framerate (averages 30 fps), and I am already multiprocessing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a [`cv2.LUT`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#lut) function. With this function you can avoid split & merge steps.